# Uber/fat jar containing SQL Server JDBC driver via Maven shade plugin

Tags: maven

I am trying to build a sample jar which contains the SQL Server JDBC driver via [Maven dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc/6.3.4.jre8-preview). The class connecting to the db and querying compiles and executes correctly in the IDE(IntelliJ).

When I execute a 'mvn clean install' or 'install' from IntelliJ, the jar built is containing only the db class that I have written but not the SQL Server JDBC jar(should be in exploded format, I suppose).

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.company</groupId>
  <artifactId>JavaMavenProject</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>JavaMavenProject</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
      <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>6.3.4.jre8-preview</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <!--For building an uber jar-->
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <phase>package</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                <!--<artifactSet>
                  &lt;!&ndash; groupId:artifactId[[:type]:classifier]&ndash;&gt;
                  <includes>
                    <include>com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc</include>
                  </includes>
                </artifactSet>-->

                <filters>
                  <filter>
                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                    <excludes>
                      <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                      <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                      <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                  </filter>
                </filters>
             </configuration>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

  </build>

</project>
```

Interesting part is that **if I include another dependency e.g: scala and provide it before sql server, the uber jar contains both the required dependencies and the sql code executes well from the target jar**. I think for some reason the sql server jdbc jar is not picked up during building the jar. The below pom works perfectly and gives the desired uber jar :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.company</groupId>
  <artifactId>JavaMavenUber</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>JavaMavenUber</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <scala.version>2.12.3</scala.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
      <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
      <version>${scala.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
      <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>6.3.4.jre8-preview</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <!--For building an uber jar-->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <artifactSet>
                <!--groupId:artifactId[[:type]:classifier]-->
                <includes>
                  <include>org.scala-lang:scala-library</include>
                  <include>com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc</include>
                </includes>
              </artifactSet>
              <filters>
                <filter>
                  <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                  <excludes>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                  </excludes>
                </filter>
              </filters>

            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

**Edit-1**: pom modified as suggested by @Gladiator

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.company</groupId>
  <artifactId>JavaMavenProject</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>JavaMavenProject</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
      <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>6.3.4.jre8-preview</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <!--For building an uber jar-->
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <phase>package</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                <shadedClassifierName>all</shadedClassifierName>

                <filters>
                  <filter>
                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                    <excludes>
                      <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                      <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                      <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                  </filter>
                </filters>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

  </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

Changes scope of below from test to compile

```
 <dependency>
  <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
  <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
  <version>6.3.4.jre8-preview</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Use below it can help

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>shade</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                    <shadedClassifierName>all</shadedClassifierName>

                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: Did the changes but the jar is unchanged

Comment: Edit-1 to the original post has the modified pom file, can you have a look ?

Comment: Surprisingly, if I include another dependency just before the sql server jdbc, the final uber jar is built and works perfectly, check my original post which has both the working and non-working pom files.

Comment: I used your pom from edit and removed pluginmanagement tag  and it worked .  I think pluginmanagement tag  is causing issue  but don't know why